# Evaluate the limit of $\frac{1}{n}{\sum_{k=1}^n}\frac{4\,k^3\,e^{\frac{k^4}{n^4}}}{n^3}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$a_n=\frac{1}{n}{\sum_{k=1}^n}\frac{4\,k^3\,e^{\frac{k^4}{n^4}}}{n^3}$$

So it seems like a Riemann sum, so writing it as a Riemann sum can help find the integral$\Rightarrow$ the limit

$$\frac{1}{n}{\sum_{k=1}^n}\frac{4\,k^3\,e^{\frac{k^4}{n^4}}}{n^3}=\frac{1}{n^4}{\sum_{k=1}^n}4k^3e^{\frac{k^4}{n^4}}=\frac{1}{n^4}{\sum_{k=1}^n}[e^{\frac{k^4}{n^4}}]'=\Delta x_{i}{\sum_{k=1}^n}[e^{\frac{k^4}{\Delta x_{i}}}]'$$

So the integral is $\int_{0}^{1}[e^{k^4}]'$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is a Riemann sum then, as $n \to \infty$, 
$$
\frac{1}{n}{\sum_{k=1}^n}\frac{4\,k^3\,e^{\frac{k^4}{n^4}}}{n^3} \to \int_0^14x^3e^{\large x^4}dx=\int_0^1\left(e^{\large x^4}\right)'dx=\left[e^{\large x^4}\frac{}{}\right]_0^1=e-1.
$$

Comment: So the function $e^{{x^4}}$ in the interval $[0,1]$ we divide it to $n$ sub-interval and in each sub interval we take the $\frac{k}{n}$ point, why $dx=\frac{1}{n^4}$ and not $dx=\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: We have $dx=\frac1n$, $x^3=\frac{k^3}{n^3}$.

Comment: Shouldn't the final answer be $e^1-e^0 = e-1$ instead of $e$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Edited. Thank you.